# How to decrease the height of the input text field in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to decrease the height of the input text field in bootstrap? My code:

**Head section:**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/defaultStyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myMenuStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="css/FiexedHeaderTableScrollingStyle.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 0px ;
            margin-top: 0px; <!-- I used this style to decrease space between fields -->
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

**Actual form code:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="addKPITODB">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label for="kpi_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">KPI Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kpi_name"
            placeholder="KPI Name" name="kpi_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group  form-group-sm">
        <label for="kpi_sql" class="col-sm-2 control-label">KPI SQL</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="K sql"
            name="kpi_sql" id="kpi_sql">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The above code gives the following output:

[image]

In the above image, the input field height is big even I am using `form-group form-group-sm`. I need to decrease the height further.

Comment: Go to --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754536/decrease-twitter-bootstrap-input-fields-height

Comment: Let me check friend.

Comment: Yes I already tried this. That is not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
input.form-control {
   height:25px !important;
}
```

Comment: !important was miss spelled, try now

Comment: You are really super. Thanks a lot. You saved my day. Really thanks.

Answer (score 1):

.form-control class in bootstrap is set to have `height: 34px` you can set it to anything you like using:

```
.form-control {
   height: 30px;
}
```

for example, if it is not working that means that your stylesheet file is being loaded **BEFORE** `bootstrap.css` file, so either add `!important` to your CSS rule or load your stylesheet **AFTER** the `bootstrap.css` file which is the preferred way.

Here is an example:

```css
.form-control {
  height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="addKPITODB">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">

        <label for="kpi_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">KPI Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kpi_name"
                placeholder="KPI Name" name="kpi_name">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group  form-group-sm">
        <label for="kpi_sql" class="col-sm-2 control-label">KPI SQL</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="K sql"
                name="kpi_sql" id="kpi_sql">
        </div>
    </div></form>
```